# error in the communication between C client and Java server

Tags: java, c, sockets

I want to send an integer to the server, increment it and send back the new number and a random String to the Client . I use this code

```
int value = htons( 4 );
int reply = 0;
send( to_server_socket, &value, sizeof( value ),0 );
recv( to_server_socket, &reply, sizeof( reply ), 0 );
printf( "got reply: %d\n", ntohs( reply ) );
```

the server code

```
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        int ClientNumber= din.readInt();
        System.out.println(ClientNumber);


        ClientNumber++;
       DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
       dos.writeInt(ClientNumber);

       String randomString= getRandomValue(10,20);
       dos.writeUTF(randomString);
```

but the server does not receive 4 but 262144 and the Reply in the Client still 0. I also have an error in the server

> java.io.EOFException  at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:323)
>     at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:572)    at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:547)     at
>   ServiceRequest.run(ServiceRequest.java:41)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Edit:

it work with htonl [send an integer from a C client to a Java server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362303/send-an-integer-from-a-c-client-to-a-java-server/16362518#16362518) i get the int but for the String i got numbers and not characters

Comment: You have already asked this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362303/send-an-integer-from-a-c-client-to-a-java-server

Comment: The code you have posted here shows you missed my final edits in my prior answer. Go back and re-read the edits here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362303/send-an-integer-from-a-c-client-to-a-java-server/16362518#16362518

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `htons` function to translate the `int` value to network byte order.

The function `htons` function is defined to rearrange bytes on little-endian hosts to network byte order (big-endian), and Java is always big-endian.

But this function translates a 16-bit value, not a 32-bit value.  Here's the bits:

```
4      = 00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000 (2^2) (little-endian)
262144 = 00000000 00000100 00000000 00000000 (2^18) (big-endian)
```

Try using the [`htonl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons) function, which translates 32-bit `int` values to network byte order.  Then this should result.

```
4      = 00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000 (2^2) (little-endian)
4      = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100 (2^2) (big-endian)
```

Answer (score 0):

262144 is Hex 0x00040000, so something changes your byte order.